# What does Dirac cones at the $K$ and $K'$ point mean?

Tags: crystals, topological-insulators, graphene

Graphene is a topological insulator with Dirac cones located at the points $K$ and $K'$ in the Brillouin zone. The bands at these points correspond to conducting edge modes. However, if we consider a system with edges, the Brillouin zone is only defined along one direction. Hence, it does not make sense to consider the $K$ and $K$' points.

I seem to have misunderstood something basic, and I would very much appreciate any clarification.

Comment: "Graphene is a topological insulator" - no, it isn't. It is not an insulator, it is a semimetal (i.e. its bandgap is zero). It is closely related to an important class of topological insulators (which are, in essence, graphene that has been modified to introduce a bandgap in a specific, symmetry-breaking way), but it is not in that class.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking the graphene band structure are not cones - the cones approximation works only close to the Dirac points, and is analogous to the effective mass approximation in gapped materials. When dealing with a finite size sample, one can thus use two approaches:

- Solve anew for the band structure of the finite sample
- Use the solution (and the approximations) for the infinite sample, and impose on it boundary conditions

The second approach is ubiquitous in studying processes in semiconductor nanostructures, but it is, of course, not suitable when studying physics of edge states or other phenomena that may depend on the shape of the boundary. Both situations are rather abundant in graphene literature, but I suspect that people working on topological insulators are in the former class, and less concerned with whether the graphene sheet was cut along a zigzag or armchair or another direction, whether this cut was regular, etc.

**Remark:** the derivation of a graphene structure and the cones approximation can be found in nearly any text on graphene or carbon nanotubes (in fact, the problem was deal with several decades before it became possible to obtaine graphene sheets, in the context of studying graphine). It is a good exercise to do it yourself, by solving the tight-binding approximation for a hexagonal lattice (keeping in mind that the primitive cell contains two identical carbon atoms).